# Multiple layers of tabination within a webpage

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, tabs

I have a question about how to add layers of tabination inside one webpage.

Currently, the pages which I would like to edit have a jQuery tab function to swap between tabs with different content. I would like to go one step further and have an encompassing tabination system with a page entry tab containing initial content and a button to the next tab; and inside the next tab have the current active tab function. Check out the picture if this is confusing:
[Image for Visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehj3y.jpg) *Edit: In the image the 'layers' should be 'sections'.*

**My current code: One layer of tabination**

**jQuery in header.php**

```
<script>
  $(function() {

    $('.tab-panels .tabs li').on('click', function(){
      var $panel = $(this).closest('.tab-panels');

      $panel.find('.tabs li.active').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');

      // Figure out which panel to show
      var panelToShow = $(this).attr('data-panelid');

      // Hide current panel
      $panel.find('.tab.active').hide(0, showNextPanel);

        // Show next panel
        function showNextPanel() {
          $(this).removeClass('active');

          $('#'+panelToShow).show(0, function() {
            $(this).addClass('active');
          });            
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

**Tabs include file**

*Styled as a horizontal bar.*

```
<div class="tabs-container">
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li data-panelid="panel1" class="active">Tab 1</li>
    <li data-panelid="panel2">Tab 2</li>            
    <li data-panelid="panel3">Tab 3</li>
    <li data-panelid="panel4">Tab 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**HTML of the webpage**

*I have wrapped each of the encompassing tabs as 'SECTIONS', and the inside tabs as 'TABS'. The header (containing the jQuery), and this page are called in another php file.*

```
<div class="section-wrap">  

    <div class="container section active" id="section1">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div>CONTENT</div>
                <div class="button-container">
                    <span>BUTTON TO NEXT SECTION</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  

    <div class="container section" id="section2">

        <div class="container tab-container">

            <!-- Incluce Tabs -->
            <?php include(ROOT_PATH . "/inc/tabs.php") ?>

            <div class="row tab active" id="panel1">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h2>SUBTITLE</h2>
                    <p>CONTENT</p>
                </div>
            </div> 

            <div class="row tab" id="panel2">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h2>SUBTITLE</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li>CONTENT</li>
                        <li>CONTENT</li>
                        <li>CONTENT</li>
                        <li>CONTENT</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row tab" id="panel3">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h2>SUBTITLE</h2>
                    <h3>SUB SUBTITLE</h3>
                    <p>CONTENT</p>
                    <h3>SUB SUBTITLE</h3>
                    <p>CONTENT</p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>                         

<div class="mobile-breadcrumb">         
    <!-- Include Breadcrumb -->
    <?php include(ROOT_PATH . "/inc/breadcrumb.php") ?>
</div>

</div>
<!-- END PAGE CONTENTS -->


<!-- Include Footer -->
<?php include(ROOT_PATH . "/inc/footer.php") ?>
```

I imagine the same jQuery script could be used to switch between sections, however I'm not sure how to implement this and would love some help. The user would not need to go back to the initial page entry 'section'. Also, the reason why I do not wish to use a different web page entirely is that the pages that this system will be implemented on are already 4 layers deep in the website.

I hope this isn't too confusing, thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely not the best way to do this but here is my current solution:

**jQuery in header**

```
  $(function() {

    $('#section1').show().siblings().hide();

    $('.section-button').find('a').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this.hash).show().siblings().hide();
    })

  });

</script>
```

**HTML of page**

```
<div class="section-wrap">  

    <div class="container section" id="section1">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <p>CONTENT</p>
                <p>CONTENT</p>
                <span class="section-button"><a href="#section2">GO TO SECTION 2</a></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  

    <div class="container section" id="section2">
        <p>CONTENT</p>
        <p>CONTENT</p>
    </div>

</div>
```